# TypeError: Could not found the Java class 'org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer'

Tags: python, java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using PyFlink. I thought all the Java dependencies are installed along with `pip install apache-flink`

The above error occurs on this line:

```
kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
    topics='mytopic',
    deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
    properties={
        'bootstrap.servers': KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS})
```

As per the error do I need to specify the kafka consumer dependency manually in the pyflink environment by downloading and adding the jar?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Python Version: 3.8.2
Java Version: java 11.0.11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Flink is a Java/Scala-based project, for both connectors and formats, implementations are available as jars

FlinkKafkaConsumer in pyflink relies on Java's FlinkKafkaConsumer implementation

You need to download the kafka connector jar package to the lib directory of pyflink. Generally, the path of the lib directory is: /usr/local/lib/python3.8.2/site-packages/pyflink/lib

```
class FlinkKafkaConsumer(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase):
    """
    The Flink Kafka Consumer is a streaming data source that pulls a parallel data stream from
    Apache Kafka. The consumer can run in multiple parallel instances, each of which will
    pull data from one or more Kafka partitions.

    The Flink Kafka Consumer participates in checkpointing and guarantees that no data is lost
    during a failure, and that the computation processes elements 'exactly once. (These guarantees
    naturally assume that Kafka itself does not lose any data.)

    Please note that Flink snapshots the offsets internally as part of its distributed checkpoints.
    The offsets committed to Kafka / Zookeeper are only to bring the outside view of progress in
    sync with Flink's view of the progress. That way, monitoring and other jobs can get a view of
    how far the Flink Kafka consumer has consumed a topic.

    Please refer to Kafka's documentation for the available configuration properties:
    http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs
    """

    def __init__(self, topics: Union[str, List[str]], deserialization_schema: DeserializationSchema,
                 properties: Dict):
        """
        Creates a new Kafka streaming source consumer for Kafka 0.10.x.

        This constructor allows passing multiple topics to the consumer.

        :param topics: The Kafka topics to read from.
        :param deserialization_schema: The de-/serializer used to convert between Kafka's byte
                                       messages and Flink's objects.
        :param properties: The properties that are used to configure both the fetcher and the offset
                           handler.
        """

        JFlinkKafkaConsumer = get_gateway().jvm
            .org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
        j_flink_kafka_consumer = _get_kafka_consumer(topics, properties, deserialization_schema,
                                                     JFlinkKafkaConsumer)
        super(FlinkKafkaConsumer, self).__init__(j_flink_kafka_consumer=j_flink_kafka_consumer)
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming, much appreciated!

Comment: Quick question, is it just a matter of adding the jars to this location or do I need to add them in the flink environment in code like this `stream_execution_environment.add_jars("file:///my/jar/path/connector1.jar", "file:///my/jar/path/connector2.jar")`

Comment: Great, this works too

Comment: I am also facing face problem. Where do I get "connector1.jar" and "connector2.jar" ?

Comment: @ChangLi  does any of you have a github repo to share on this? Would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AcK does any of you have a github repo to share on this? Would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Kafka connectors were discontinued as from Flink 1.12. Check out on the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/release-notes/flink-1.12/#connectors-and-formats). You can now use universal kafka connectors. Read more on [cloudera](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Flink-Kafka-Connector-java-lang-NoSuchMethodError/td-p/336720).

```
In Flink 1.12 we removed the Kafka 0.10.x and 0.11.x connectors. Please use the universal Kafka connector which works with any Kafka cluster version after 0.10.2.x.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).